# How to make VLC always plays in fullscreen mode

Tags: fullscreen, vlc, playlist

I am using VLC media player with playlist, which contains IP TV addresses. Using remote from my sound card I can switch TV channels. Sometimes, while changing channel, VLC exits from fullscreen mode and to return to the fullscreen mode I need to push "F" button or make "mouse double click". I cannot find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with VLC. See the following [ticket](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/17054) on trac which states in the description that:

> on video change VLC quits fullscreen, which need to be reapplied manually

Also, note the ongoing threads over at the [videolan.org forum](https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=VLC%20mediaplayer%20fullscreen%20playlist%20site:forum.videolan.org).

What you can try is starting the playlist in fullscreen mode by using the terminal:

[image: fullscreen parameter]

Start your playlist like this:

```
vlc --fullscreen /Path/to/playlist.pl
```

*Please note: I post this as an answer as it is too long for a comment and should either point you in the right directions, or bring you to the conclusion that this is a known issue, and therefore cannot be solved at the time being.*

Comment: Yes, it is known issue. The ticket, you've shared, recently was reopened by me :). Thanks for the advice, I will try your solution.

Comment: Alright, that's great, so the issue is in the pipeline. I guess you could also try and contact the developers directly via the official VLC IRC channel (irc.freenode.org, #videolan) in order to find out how complex the issue is.

Comment: I think I'm not the only one who does not know much about IRC technology :). If someone feels himself like me - please read the following [article](http://irchelp.org/irchelp/irctutorial.html).

Comment: Good news! I've asked j-b developer in #videolan IRC channel about this issue in a context if it will be fixed in 2.2.5 VLC revision. The answer was "yes"!

Comment: Thanks for checking! Good news!